# Afinal, por que o código fonte PHP não aparece no navegador?

Tags: php

Bom, sei que PHP é um pré-processador de HTML, sei que ele é interpretado pelo PHP e é renderizado na página porém o código fonte não aparece. Mas é realmente seguro? Sei que é possível capturar os resultados da página, mas desconheço de capturar a página real em si, mas mesmo assim, é seguro deixar informações sensíveis nos blocos de código fonte PHP?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nada é seguro se não souber o que está fazendo. Quase todos os sites existentes hoje na internet são inseguros porque quase todos são feitos por pessoas que acham que podem decorar umas receitas de bolo e isto basta para fazer um site.

Curiosamente em sistemas para desktop que não envolvem internet a segurança costuma poder ser negligenciada sem grandes problemas. Mas essas pessoas que não sabem o que estão fazendo preferem fazer para web, até por não saberem nem que a melhor solução provavelmente é para desktop mesmo, ou mobile. Web deveria ser a última opção quando as outras não são adequadas. Ou seja, é uma soma de erros.

Não basta responder esta pergunta para manter segurança. E todo mundo acha que basta essa e mais uma meia dúzia e está tudo certo. Segurança é um alvo móvel, muda sempre, por isso só dá para fazer seguro se entender muito de computação.

Para responder esta pergunta, sim, é seguro se tudo for feito certo. Se fizer errado não é. Pra fazer certo envolve muita coisa, mas a principal é configurar o servidor adequadamente para processar páginas PHP sempre e não as expor. Mas não ache que isto é suficiente.

Se tudo estiver certo toda requisição a algo com extensão `.php` será entregue para o interpretador do PHP que executará o código no servidor e emitirá uma resposta para o servidor HTTP que mandará para o navegador. Então, a não ser que faça algo absurdamente errado, quase impossível, nada do código PHP irá para o servidor HTTP e consequentemente para o cliente. O código PHP geralmente é misto de HTML com PHP, só a parte do HTML e o que o código de programação gerar na requisição é que irá para o navegador.

O fato de não ir para o navegador não quer dizer que está seguro, apenas que ele não irá para lá em condições normais.

E não confie em pessoas aleatórias na internet. Existem alguns mitos nas respostas postadas aqui, mas a maioria está certa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Adotar um framework já não seria uma medida para aumentar a segurança?

Comment: Não sei, muitos são causadores de insegurança, e se usar errado pode ser mais fácil causar uma insegurança. Eles ajudam não cometer os bobos, mas torna mais fácil cometer os cabeludos. Quanto mais complexidade, mais abstração, mais cada adiciona, mais fácil é cometer um erro e não perceber. Claro que entre fazer tudo errado porque não tem a menor noção do que está fazendo e um *framework*, é melhor o segundo, mas continua não sendo uma boa solução, a solução é aprender tudo direito, se dedicar, ou contratar alguém que saiba fazer.

Answer (score 8):

O código PHP roda somente no servidor. O motor do PHP utiliza o seu código para gerar o código HTML que é enviado para quem solicitou a página.

Em geral não é possível determinar se um trecho de HTML estava escrito como HTML mesmo no código fonte original, ou se foi gerado por algum motor (como uma aplicação em Node.js, C#, PHP etc.). Mesmo em casos nos quais as bibliotecas de uso mais comum deixem suas "marcas" (como comentários HTML bem específicos, ou trechos repetidos e conhecidos por quem é da área), não é possível fazer engenharia reversa e "adivinhar" o fonte PHP apenas pelo HTML que desceu.

Então, a menos que alguém tenha acesso ao FTP do seu servidor, é seguro dizer que não conseguirão ver o seu código apenas pelo HTML gerado.

Os riscos de se colocar informações sensíveis em código fonte são os seguintes:

- Se o seu código estiver em algum repositório como Github ou Bitbucket, quem tiver acesso ao repositório poderá ver as informações sensíveis;
- Se alguém é inexperiente o suficiente para colocar informação sensível em código, não seria surpreendente se a pessoa cometesse um deslize que transformasse o código fonte PHP com informação sensível em texto de página (já vi acontecer mais vezes do que consigo contar). Nesse caso o problema não é o PHP em si, mas sim o desenvolvedor.

Comment: E também deixar alguma abertura em algum $_GET ou no servidor que alguém consiga enviar um arquivo malicioso.

Comment: Não entendi o negativo aqui.

Answer (score 3):

Eu tenho pouca experiência com PHP, então sintam-se à vontade para editar e melhorar essa resposta.

O motivo do código-fonte do PHP não aparecer é que ele não é código HTML, ele é executado/interpretado pelo servidor e esse código produz código HTML.

Eu mesmo pude constar isso ao tentar fazer um código PHP básico (Hello World) numa página HTML sem um servidor rodando por trás, e o meu browser (Chrome no caso) simplesmente comentou o código PHP ao abrir a página. Fiquei frustrado na hora. Mas depois que pesquisei, vi que o **código PHP é usado pelo servidor,  não pelo browser**, assim um ambiente de experimentações para PHP deve ter um servidor local, como um Tomcat ou algo similar.

Resumindo: o PHP é processado pelo servidor e o browser apenas recebe os resultados dele e os processa para visualização. Fazer com que o browser executasse código PHP seria perigoso, na minha opinião, pois abriria muitas brechas de segurança.

Answer (score 3):

O Navegador não tem recursos para executar uma lógica PHP, apenas lógicas de Javascript.

O browser em si, recebe e renderiza o HTML considerando o que houver de estilo definido pelo CSS. Ao mesmo tempo, ele também tem o poder de interpretar as lógicas de JavaScript, que é o que dá poder às páginas.

Quem tem poder para interpretar o PHP, é o servidor WEB. Que interpreta e dispara o pacote HTTP com o corpo HTML (html, css e js).

O navegador possui uma engine JavaScript, que é tipo o interpretador de PHP no servidor, porém não executa PHP, apenas JavaScript.

Respondendo sua pergunta, sim, você pode colocar informações no seu PHP que, na teoria, elas não podem ser exibidas para o usuário de forma alguma.

Digo na teoria pois, se a aplicação não tiver segura ou houver bugs que você não viu, algum usuário pode fazer algo inesperado e quebrar sua lógica, gerando erros e permitindo (talvez) que a informação contida no PHP vá para o browser por causa do erro. Mas, repito, isso não significa que o navegador irá rodar o código, ele não tem 'poder' para isso.